# selecting nth match of a regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string in the format of 0`0:00:00:0000`. I want to capture the last `:` i.e before `0000` and change it to another character. How do I select only that one `:` ?. I was wondering if there is a way of selecting a character preceeded by other regexp match(as there is a way of selecting characters followed by a regexpr match with (`?=pattern)` or a way of counting the matched `:` and only selecting let's say the 4th match. I am using ruby 1.8.7 implementantion of regular expressions. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a look ahead assertion like this:

```
/:(?=[^:]*$)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the last match

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > "0:00:00:0000".gsub(/(:)([^:]+)$/, "x\\2")
 => "0:00:00x0000"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use [String#[]=](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/String#%5B%5D=-instance_method) method:

```
str = "0:00:00:0000"
str[/(:)[^:]+$/, 1] = '*'
str                                       # => "0:00:00*0000"
```

Comment: This is a little more obtuse than the `str.sub!` method, but it does the same job. Anchoring the pattern helps simplify the regexp even if it makes it look more magical.